# Enable jQuery UI drag and drop on Surface Pro tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

As the title says, I'm trying to enable drag and drop on the Sufrace Pro 3 tablet.

Is drag and drop functionality even supported on these devices? If so, how would I go about enabling this feature? If not, how can I workaround this?

I'm trying to get jQuery UI's drag and drop feature to work. Here is a basic example I am trying to get working:

```js
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

```css
#draggable {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar issue a while back. You need to change the [`touch-action` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767313.aspx) of the desired elements to `none`. In this case, since you're using jQueryUI, you would apply this to the `.ui-draggable`/`.ui-droppable` elements.

You will also need to add the `-ms` vendor prefix, therefore you would use `-ms-touch-action: none`:

```
.ui-draggable, .ui-droppable {
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That was so simple. It actually worked. I thought I would have to rewrite all my JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! saved my Day!

Answer (score 4):

There is an updated version that works for Windows 10. https://github.com/RWAP/jquery-ui-touch-punch/blob/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js

Comment: This is solution for 2020+.

Comment: Working great on a Samsung A9 as of 2024. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com) which enables the use of jQuery UI on touch devices.

You only need to insert it right after jQuery ui like:

```
<script src="path/to/file/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/file/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/file/jquery-touch-punch.js"></script>
```

No code needed

Comment: thanks, I will give this a try after. It looks like Joshs solution worked